# Authenticating a user after metamask stopped injecting web3js into the browser

Tags: authentication, ethereum, web3js, metamask

I want to create a passwordless authentication (using Metamask to sign a message; then validate the message on the server and then assign a JWT token). I want the part for signing a message to be written inside a vanilla JavaScript file.

Most of the articles I see online are from 2018 and talk about using `web3.eth.personal.sign` method from web3 which being injected into the browser by Metamask. However I understand this is no longer the case with Metamask. Now that web3 is not injected anymore, what functions do I call to sign a message with Metamask?

##### What I've attempted...

I understand there's a `window.ethereum` object injected into the browser but I can't seem to find an equivalent function in the Metamask documentation for `web3.eth.personal.sign`

I'm guessing the alternative is to use `web3` without `window.ethereum` but how to I inject this into a vanilla JavaScript file? Also how do I ensure that the message is signed by Metamask if I just use web3 as standalone?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [web3 npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/web3). Then you can connect it to Metamask with:

```
import Web3 from "web3";

window.ethereum.request({ method: "eth_requestAccounts" });
const web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum);
```

This will make metamask popup and ask the user to select an account.

Then to sign a message you can call web3 with:

```
const dataToSign = "My test message";
const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
const signature = await web3.eth.sign(dataToSign, accounts[0]);
```

Documentation: https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.3.4/web3-eth.html#sign

This will cause Metamask to ask the user to sign the data with their currently active account. I'm not sure how to validate if the signature is correct.